# Get Coordinates for given Location

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, google-maps, geocoding, latitude-longitude

OK, here's what I want to implement and I need your ideas :

- Input a geo location by name/address/etc (e.g. `London, Oxford Street 20`)
- Get the point's **longitude/latitude**

---

**My Questions :**

- How would you go about that?
- Is using *Google Maps API* (that's what I first thought of) my only solution?

*It'd be better if the service used CAN be freely integrated in a commercial app - so any idea is welcome... :-)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built in API for that.
For iOS 5 and newer you can use [CLGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder) and for older version you will need to use some extern libraries.

Just call

```
- (void)geocodeAddressString:(NSString *)addressString completionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)completionHandler
```

where you want to get the location. It runs async and in the `completionHandler` you will get an array of all possible placemarks for your address where the first one is the most accurate. As apple says:

> For most geocoding requests, this array should contain only one
>   entry. However, forward-geocoding requests may return multiple
>   placemark objects in situations where the specified address could not
>   be resolved to a single location.

*Off topic:*
Am I the only one whos first thoughts about `Oxford` was "What does he mean with this weird Hex value?"

Comment: That will restrict him to iOS 5.X. As @kentoh has told, should he not be considering web services rather than CLGeoCoder?

Comment: As i said, there are some open source libraries available which works for prior versions. But if he don't need support for older iOS version `CLGeocoder` is a good thing. I try to convince all my customers to drop support for older versions since iOS 5 has a market share of over 80% and iOS 6 is comming soon.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is basically **geocoding**. Major map providers like Google, Bing and Yahoo (and many more) all offer some form of Geocoding API for you to take advantage of. Check out the following quick links:

- [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)
- [Bing Locations API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx)
- [Yahoo! Maps Web Services (Geocoding API)](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/geocode.html)

**Edit:** (just saw the objective-c tag)

Note that these are non-native solutions. However, the provided APIs are typically REST-based (with output as xml/json), it shouldn't be hard for you to consume these services to grab the gecoded lat-long that you want from within your app.