# Find location in iPhone by name (duplicate)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

**I am new to iOS application development.
So, i would like to ask about how can i get the coordinates of location by name .**

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_7_Location_Application

Comment: http://www.theappguruz.com/sample-code/using-gps-device-get-current-location-ios/

Comment: Thanks.but there is some miss understanding i am asking about user can give location name and wants to the latitude and longitude.

Comment: This question appears basic to be asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CLGeocoder` to get the cordinates of location (Forward geoCoding).

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:YOUR_LOCATION completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error)
         {
             NSLog(@"completed");
             if ( error )
             {
                 NSLog(@"error = %@", error );
             }
             else
             {
                 //Here you get information about the place in placemarks array
             }
         }];
```

Reffer [Link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/forward-geocoding-with-clgeocoder--mobile-11011)

Comment: thanks for your help
and also vote for my question so that i will vote for you too. thanks.

Comment: it works. hurrah thanks dear.

Comment: Thanks. Suhail once again.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get the users position and display it or do you want the user to type in an address and then display the coordinates of that address?

Get the users position in iOS7 (or older):
http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/getting-the-users-location-using-corelocation/

For iOS8 you need to make some small adjustments:
http://matthewfecher.com/app-developement/getting-gps-location-using-core-location-in-ios-8-vs-ios-7/

If you want the coordinates from an adress you can use this method from CLGeocoder:

```
- (void)geocodeAddressString:(NSString *)addressString completionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)completionHandler
```

Unfortunatley this does not work very well outside of USA. There are other services that you can use but they will cost you some money to use. Have a look at this thread for more info: [Get Coordinates for given Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339349/get-coordinates-for-given-location)